# AppleScript: how to get the current directory of the topmost Terminal

Tags: terminal, applescript, working-directory

I want to get the current directory of the topmost Terminal tab/window (via AppleScript or something else, it doesn't really matter). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution.

get_foregroundterminal_curdir_fast.scpt:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "lsof -a -p `lsof -a -c bash -u $USER -d 0 -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{if($NF==\"" & (tty of front tab of front window) & "\"){print $2}}'` -d cwd -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $NF}'"
end tell
```

I use `lsof` itself to get PID of the bash shell of the corresponding Terminal window. This is MUCH faster than using `fuser` (milliseconds vs. seconds).

Answer (score 3):

I got pointed to the question when posting a question about how to find the current directory in Applescript so I'm posting this answer to let future referred readers know the excepted answer has a flaw in it.

**If the current directory path has a *SPACE* character in it, then it only  returns the portion of the path after (the last) *SPACE* character!**

Use this simple script instead, it handles *every* path: `tell application "Terminal" to set currentDirectory to (do shell script "pwd")`

Comment: It is not said that the path has a space.

Comment: @ppasler - He says he wants "the current path". Unless the programmer is in complete control of the terminal as well, the user could easily "cd" into a directory with a space in its path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have one solution.

get_foregroundterminal_proclist.scpt:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do shell script "fuser " & (tty of front tab of front window)
end tell
```

get_foregroundterminal_curdir.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

function pwdx {
    lsof -a -p $1 -d cwd -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
}

for pid in $(osascript "$(dirname "$0")/get_foregroundterminal_proclist.scpt"); do
    pwdx $pid
    break # break on first
done
```