# Find the Current Directory of the Current Terminal Tab in Python

Tags: python, macos, bash, applescript

Is there a way in Python, subprocessing Bash and/or AppleScript, for me to get the current working directory of the frontmost Terminal.app tab and window in OSX?

I've tried the solution in [AppleScript: how to get the current directory of the topmost Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16073987/130427). It doesn't work in my script.

I use Python to run AppleScript through the following function:

```
def run(script):
    "Returns the result of running string in osascript (Applescript)"

    if hasattr(script, "encode"): #Assumes Python 3
        script = script.encode("utf-8")

    osa = Popen(["osascript", "-"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    results, err = osa.communicate(script)

    if err:
        raise Exception(err)

    return results.decode("utf-8")
```

I have tried using the suggested answer through the following call:

```
def getTerminalDir():
    script = '''
        tell application "Terminal"
            do shell script "lsof -a -p `lsof -a -c bash -u $USER -d 0 -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{if($NF==\"" & (tty of front tab of front window) & "\"){print $2}}'` -d cwd -n | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $NF}'"
        end tell
    '''
    result = run(script)
    return result
```

When I do that, I get the following error:

```
Exception: 126:127: syntax error: Expected end of line but found “"”. (-2741)
```

Comment: That solution doesn't work in my script. Which is why I broadened the scope of the question to include other languages.

Comment: @ChrisRedford, then you should state that in your question; what you've tried, why it doesn't work

Comment: I second wnnmaw's comment. Especially since that answer worked for me.

Comment: There. I have explained.

Comment: BTW: the AppleScript code works when executed directly in AppleScript... (but I assume not perfectly with tabs)

Comment: Right. I experienced it working in the AppleScript script editor (but only for the first tab) as well.

Comment: Replacing "front tab" with "selected tab" should solve that

Comment: Indeed, it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Thanks for the useful AppleScript insights that helped lead to this solution, [Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577225/zero).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_output, STDOUT

def runAppleScript(script):
    "Returns the result of running string in osascript (Applescript)"

    if hasattr(script, "encode"): #Assumes Python 3
        script = script.encode("utf-8")

    osa = Popen(["osascript", "-"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    results, err = osa.communicate(script)
    if err:
        raise Exception(err)

    return results.decode("utf-8")

def runBash(command):
    output = check_output(command, stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
    return output

def getCurrentTerminalTTYS():
    script = '''
    tell application "Terminal"
        return (tty of selected tab of front window)
    end tell
    '''
    result = runAppleScript(script)
    return result.strip()

def getPathForTTYS(ttys):
    lsof = runBash('lsof').split('\n')
    process = None
    for line in lsof:
        if ttys in line:
            process = line.split()[1]
            break
    path = None
    for line in lsof:
        if 'cwd' in line and process in line:
            path = ' '.join(line.split()[8:])
            break
    return path

def getCurrentTerminalPath():
    ttys = getCurrentTerminalTTYS()
    return getPathForTTYS(ttys)
```

This can be stored as a string using

```
path = getCurrentTerminalPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen
    activate
    do script "pwd" in selected tab of window 1
    set tabContents to contents of selected tab of window 1
end tell

set myPath to paragraph -2 of (do shell script "grep . <<< " & quoted form of tabContents)
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt but I have a custom bash prompt, so this just greps part of the prompt involving my username and the machine name.

Comment: You may be able to get the path by adjusting the paragraph number. The grep command simply removes the empty lines found at the bottom of contents.